# Undefined property: Craft\WebApp::$cache

Tags: error-message

Just ran into this error while developing a plugin.  Not doing much of anything special, just editing and renaming a few templates.

What could cause this error to happen?

Answer (score 3):

Upon looking at the `craft/runtime/logs/phperrors.log` I noticed the following error being reported:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting! in /Users/username/path/to/website/craft/app/framework/base/CModule.php
```

To fix the issue, I updated the following line in my `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

To something higher:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=500
```

This error might be thrown in other scenarios as well as this fix seems pretty specific to having XDebug installed. In any case, these steps helped me get it resolved.